# Django bulk_create with get_or_create() on m2m field

Tags: python, django, django-models, bulk

I want to create a lot of Product objects with `bulk_create`. The problem is one of the fields which is `m2m` type. I need to extract ids from comma separated string. I do it using `get_or_create()` but `bulk_create` does not work then. I know I should think about using `through` but I do not really know how, especially together with `get_or_create()`.

My code example:

```
def create_objs(row_iter):
    objs = [dict(
        name=row['name'],
        type=row['type'],
        my_m2m_field=self.get_m2m_ids(row['m2m']),
    ) for index, row in row_iter]
    products = Product.objects.bulk_create(
        [Product(**params) for params in objs]
    )
    return products

def get_m2m_ids(data):
    m2m_ids = []
    if data:
        for i in data.split(', '):
            m2m_ids.append(MyM2mModel.objects.get_or_create(title=i)[0].pk)
    return m2m_ids
```

Structure example:

```
name    type    m2m

'n1'    't1'    'm11, m12, m13'
'n2'    't2'    'm21'
'n3'    't3'    'm31, m32'
(...)
```

How am I going to do it the proper way?

Comment: A suggestion. can you make it a two step process , create Product objects via bulk_create and then later add objects in ManyToManyField field.